How to add a whitespace after double slashes in Visual Studio
I'm trying to make Visual Studio insert a whitespace after toggling comments.
So when I use Ctrl + / instead of:
//int i = 1;

I'd like to get:
// int i = 1;

No luck so far. Does anybody know if it's possible?
